# Обрезка изображения в ImageView android

Tags: android, imageview

Подскажите, как можно обрезать изображение в `ImageView` по вылезающей стороне? То бишь есть `ImageView`, допустим 100 на 100, в одном случае картинка имеет размер 120х100, во втором 100х120 (соотношение wh). Необходимо вписать их в этот `ImageView` так, чтобы в первом случае обрезалась по w - при том, чтобы центр изображения соввпадал с центром `ImageView`, во втором по h при таких же условиях. Картинки берутся с сервера, не из `res`. `centerCrop` не привёл к успеху, все равно изображение вписывается в ImageView и скейлится, то бишь параметр 120 превращается в 100, а другой соответствующим образом сжимается.

Отвечаю на комментарий.

У меня логика очень глубоко идет. Вкратце я сделал слайдер, это ViewFlipper, в который добавляются View состоящие из картинки (match_parent, match_parent), двух текствью (несущественно). Он находится в RelativeView и в ней он занимает (match_parent, match_parent). По макетам слайдер должен иметь соотношение почти 2 к 1 (80 к 39) а картинка имеет соотношение что то вроде 25 к 9 и следовательно надо её обрезать по краям. Слайдеру при добавлении на фрагмент жестко задаются границы (в зависимости от размера экрана). В итоге мои манипуляции приводят к тому, что изображение уползает вправво за экран, или вписывается по ширине. Ничего больше добиться не получилось ни с библиотеками, ни без

```
    slider = (Slider) mainView.findViewById(R.id.mainPageSlider);
    Decorator.setRectSize(slider, 640, 312);
    slider.setSlides(Data.slides, getActivity());
```

сам слайдер

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parent">
    <ViewFlipper
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/flipper"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

view c картинкой

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image_view" />
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>
    <com.widget.lavkaviews.text.Text
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

код

```
public class SlideView extends RelativeLayout {

    Slideble slide;

    public SlideView(Context context, Slideble slide) {
        super(context);
        this.slide = slide;
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.widget_slider_item, this);
        setText();
        setSecond();
        setImageView();
    }

    private void setText() {
        Text text = (Text) findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setTextColor(Decorator.WHITE);
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(40));
        text.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(5),
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(3),
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(3),
                Decorator.SLIDER_SHADOW_COLOR
        );
        text.setText(slide.getText());
    }

    private void setSecond() {
        Text second = (Text) findViewById(R.id.second);
        second.setTextColor(Decorator.WHITE);
        second.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(24));
        second.setShadowLayer(
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(4),
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(3),
                Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(3),
                Decorator.SLIDER_SHADOW_COLOR
        );
        second.setText(slide.getSecond());
    }

    private void setImageView() {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        Decorator.setRectSize(imageView, 640, 312);
        imageView.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        new DownloadImageTask(imageView)
                .execute(slide.getPhotoUrl());
    }
//        imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(slide.getPhotoUrl()));
//        Decorator.setRectSize(imageView, 640, 312);
//        Picasso.with(getContext())
//                .load(slide.getPhotoUrl())
//                .fit()
//                .centerCrop()
//                .into(imageView);
//        Glide.with(getContext())
//                .load(slide.getPhotoUrl())
//                .override(Decorator.getWidthBasedOnIPhone640(640), Decorator.getHeightBasedOnIPhone960(312))
//                .centerCrop()
//                .into(imageView);
//        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(slide.getPhotoUrl(), imageView, Decorator.getImageOptions(slide.getDrawable()));
//    }

    class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon11;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `centerCrop` работает именно так как вы описали. Если он не работает вы делаете что-то не так. Покажите ваш код и ссылку на картинку

Comment: Вот в чем дело, я использую universal-image-loader, но с ним centerCrop похоже не работает

Comment: Да, это известный баг в image лоадере. Попробуйте вместо него Glide.

Comment: Или используйте Picasso, тоже хорошая либа.

Comment: Glide в данном случае более документированый. Но все равно не выходит. Делаю Glide.with(getContext()).load(slide.getPhotoUrl()).centerCrop().into(imageView); внутри моего view, но результат тако же, как и при использовании уил

Comment: А вы ссылочку на картинку и код(xml с imageView) все же покажите